# How to reference a bunch of just-added list items in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do you get a reference to a bunch of li's that were just appended to a ul

Say I have a list:

```
<ul id="mylist">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

Now I'm appending several more li's to the above ul, so:

```
$('mylist').append(response);
```

response looks like this:

```
"<li>3</li>
 <li>4</li>
 <li>5</li>"
```

I want to attach a click handler to the newly appended li's, but how do I get a reference those li's?

UPDATE:
ul#mylist is within a popup and is not initially visible, and this popup is shown when another button is clicked:

```
$mybtn.click(function(){
  $('#mylist').show();
});
```

So, where would I define the "on" handler? if I do it within he button click handler, then it will attach the "on" handler multiple times, right, each time the button is clicked?  I can't also define the "on" handler on page load, because mylist is not visible then.

Comment: the `.on()` handler would then be bound to any static element that exists at page load, such as `$(document).on('click', '#mylist li', function(){....});`

Comment: Perfect, thanks, this syntax helped me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the elements before you append them.

```
var els = $(response).appendTo('#mylist')
                     .on("click", function() { /* your code */ });
```

---

Or if it's only for the handler, you could just have a delegate handler on your `ul`, and not worry about it.

```
// on page load
$('#mylist').on("click", "li", function() { /* your code */ });
```

---

```
// on response
$('#mylist').append(response);
```

Comment: Thanks! But please see my update, I forgot to mention that initially.  I'm wondering where to define $('#mylist').on

Comment: Hmm,  but it actually seems to work even if I define the on('click') handler on page load.

Comment: @Prabhu: Right. That's event delegation. Good idea to read up on it a little.

Comment: My confusion is how are we able to attach a click handler to an element that is not visible?

Comment: @Prabhu: Visibility doesn't mean you can't select it and add handlers. As long as the element is present on the page, it can have `display:none`, and it will still be able to be manipulated.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$('#mylist').on('click', 'li', function() { console.log('whatever'); });
```

Comment: In that case use $(document).on('click', '#mylist li', function() { console.log('whatever'); });

Comment: Thank you, ended up using this method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access strictly last added elements, you can traverse it in multiple ways:

You can go $("ul#mylist li:last-child"), or $("ul#mylist li:nth-child(n)") or edit them, adding them a class before appending, so you can mark them visually as last addition.